# cout a string gets the address instead of value

Tags: c++, macros, cout

There is a macro defined as below:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
typedef wchar_t     TCHAR;
#define TEXT(quote) L##quote
#else
typedef char        TCHAR;
#define TEXT(quote) quote
#endif
```

When I try to print a message using std::cout as below:

```
TCHAR* test = TEXT("test");
cout << test;
```

What I get the address such as 00D82110 instead of the value "test".

Can anybody give any suggestion how can I print the value here? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `wcout` instead of `cout` for wide characters. Do this:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
    typedef wchar_t     TCHAR;
    #define TEXT(quote) L##quote
    #define COUT        wcout
#else
    typedef char        TCHAR;
    #define TEXT(quote) quote
    #define COUT        cout
#endif
```

and then:

```
TCHAR* test = TEXT("test");
COUT << test;
```

Comment: Not "probably", but "definately". `cout` does not support `wchar_t` data, and `wcout` does not support `char` data.  Passing a `wchar_t*` to `cout` and a `char*` to `wcout` both end up calling the `void*` streaming operator,  which is why a memory address is being printed out instead of text.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I know. I was leaving room for suggestion of other methods (UTF8-format strings and such!) :D